# How do I fix this infinite loop / StackOverFlow error?

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, stack-overflow, infinite-loop

I need to get a method from Form1, but when I call it, I get an infinite loop error. I am getting this because I am making a new GameManager class at the begining of Form1 and I am makeing a new Form1 in GameManager. How can I get a method from form1 into GameManager without getting this infinite loop error?

Form1:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CatAndMouse
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        GameManager myGM = new GameManager();
        int dir = 0;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            newGame();
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.myGM != null)
                this.myGM.paint(e.Graphics);
            //e.Graphics.DrawImage(imgMouse.Images[0], pointXMouse, pointYMouse);
            //e.Graphics.DrawImage(imgCat.Images[0], 50, 100);
            //e.Graphics.DrawImage(imgCheese.Images[0], 75, 100);
        }

        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
            {
                dir = 0;
            }
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
            {
                dir = 1;
            }
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
            {
                dir = 2;
            }
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
            {
                dir = 3;
            }
        }
        public void newGame()
        {
            timer1.Start();
            myGM.newGame(imgCat, imgMouse, imgCheese);
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox1.Refresh();
        }
        public int getDir()
        {
            return dir;
        }
    }
}
```

GameManager:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CatAndMouse
{
    class GameManager
    {
        Form1 myForm = new Form1();
        Cat ca1 = new Cat();
        Mouse m = new Mouse();
        Cheese ch = new Cheese();
        int amount = 5;
        int catdir = 0;
        Timer time = new Timer();
        public ImageList imgCat = new ImageList();
        public ImageList imgMouse = new ImageList();
        public ImageList imgCheese = new ImageList();

        public void newGame(ImageList cat, ImageList mouse, ImageList cheese)
        {
            imgCat = cat;
            imgMouse = mouse;
            imgCheese = cheese;
            time.Start();
        }

        public void move()
        {
            ca1.Move(amount);
            m.Move(amount);
        }

        public void paint(Graphics g)
        {
            g.DrawImage(imgCat.Images[0], ca1.getLocation());
        }

        private void time_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            move();
            getDir();
        }
        public void getDir()
        {
            catdir = myForm.getDir();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What method are you trying to access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass your form object as a parameter to your GameManager object.  For example, in your constructor for GameManager make another arguement 'Form1 form' and do myForm = form;

when calling the constructor from Form1 pass 'this' as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

also if you don't want to pass a reference to a whole form you can pass just a delegate to `GameManager` constructor. More info about delegates [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173172%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Add a constructor to `GameManager`

```
Form1 myForm;
public GameManager(Form1 form)
{
    myForm = form;
}
```

Then `Form1`

```
GameManager myGM;
public Form1()
{
     myGM = new GameManager(this);
}
```